# Template parse errors by using Mat select angular 5

Tags: angular-material, angular5

[image]

```
   <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" multiple>
        <mat-option></mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

I am using mat select multi select dropdown . I have imported 
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatSelect} from '@angular/material';
import {MatFormFieldControl} from '@angular/material/';

But I am facing this error and unable to proceed.

Answer (score -1):

To use the CdkOverlayOrigin directive, you will need to import its module into your application:

```
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        OverlayModule,
        ...
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```